# Como ler um arquivo .txt no Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Estou tentando ler todo conteúdo de um arquivo `.txt` através do Electron possuindo os seguintes arquivos:

> script / index.js
>
> index.html
>
> file.txt
>
> package.json

### index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

function read_file(){
    try {
        var data = fs.readFileSync('../file.txt', 'utf8');
        console.log(data.toString());
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error:', e.stack);
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Reading File</title>
        <script src="script/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="read_file()">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Na hora de executar o Button do HTML, aparece esse erro:

> Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../file.txt'

O que tem de errado nesse código que não dá para ler o arquivo via console?

Comment: E se tirar o `../` do caminho do arquivo, o que acontece?

Comment: Aqui funcionou, mas porque precisei tirar esse (../) ? Porque o que veio pela cabeça era para o index.js ler o diretório anterior.. que estranho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não adianta ler caminhos absolutos ou relativos, o arquivo esta dentro do "app" (em `assets`, geralmente empacotado no `.asar` LEIA: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging)

Pela lógica (estou sem electron nesta máquina, irei editar assim que possivel), basta não usar o `../` porque o `file.txt` esta no mesmo nivel que a aplicação executa.

Mas é provavel que para evitar qualquer tipo de problema usar o caminho absoluto vai ajudar, mas para isto é preciso saber aonde começa, você pode até usar diretamente algo como:

```
a/b/c/d/e/f.txt
```

Mas também pode optar por usar o `__dirname`, algo como:

```
fs.readFileSync('file://' + __dirname + '/file.txt', 'utf8');
```

Que creio que irá facilitar muito, principalmente se usa o `.asar`

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o caminho que vc esta passando para abrir não existe.

Use caminhos absolutos e não relativos, para evitar esse tipo de falha.

Exemplos

Quero abrir um arquivo na minha home, `/home/user/file.txt`

Quero abrir um arquivo no meu Desktop, `/home/user/Desktop/file.txt`

Quero abrir um arquivo na mesma pasta, que estou rodando o programa `./file.txt`