# Electron - BrowserWindow não carrega páginas com o diretório diferente do root

Tags: javascript, electron

Comecei a desenvolver uma aplicação com electron, nunca tinha usado a framework antes, sempre costumei por fins de organização colocar os arquivos em diretórios separados, atualmente essa é a minha estrutura de arquivos:

```
IVarejo
|_ package.json
|_ assets
|_ node_modules
|_ src
|  |_ main.js
|_ ui
   |_ index.html
   |_ login.html
   |_ style.css
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ivarejo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Um software ERP",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "author": "Samuel Ives",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^7.1.2",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "node-forge": "^0.9.1",
    "xml-crypto": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let win = null;

app.on('ready', ()=>{
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 600, height: 400});
  win.on('closed', ()=>{
      win = null;
  });

  win.loadFile("../ui/login.html");
});
```

Se eu tento carregar o arquivo login.html que está na pasta ui uma tela em branco é mostrada.

Porém se eu mover o arquivo para a pasta IVarejo e mudar a linha para o seguinte: `win.loadFile("login.html");` vai simplesmente funcionar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então por que os arquivos html devem estar no diretório raiz?

Comment: E isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415240/3635 resolve?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento quando eu for empacotar o programa para distribuir, ele vai carregar o aplicativo de dentro da aplicação?

Comment: +ou-, na verdade eu "acho" que ele extrai na TEMP do sistema operacional (usuário atual), é um controle do "electron"

Answer (score -1):

Fala amigo! Então, tenta isso:

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/ui/login.html`);
```

A variável **__dirname** é uma variável global do Node.js que retornar o diretório atual da app.

Qualquer coisa é só comunicar, amigo!